# How do I make this query with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I have a table of services:

```
    Column    |         Type          |                           Modifiers                           
--------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 service_id   | integer               | not null default nextval('services_service_id_seq'::regclass)
 service_name | character varying(40) | not null
```

I also have a table of subservices:

```
     Column      |         Type          |                              Modifiers                              
-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 subservice_id   | integer               | not null default nextval('subservices_subservice_id_seq'::regclass)
 subservice_name | character varying(40) | not null
```

And finally I have a join table for the 2, service_subservices:

```
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------------+---------+-----------
 service_id    | integer | 
 subservice_id | integer |
```

So each service can have multiple subservices.  How do I create a query that will show me all of the subservice for a particular service?  Or do I have the tables wrong and need to restructure my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a table structure typical of a many-to-many relationship. You could get the list of subservices with:

```
SELECT ssvc.subservice_name FROM service svc, service_subservice ss, subservice ssvc
WHERE svc.id = ss.service_id AND ssvc.id = ss.subservice_id AND svc.id = ?
```

However, if you are modeling a one-to-many relationship, you should use a simpler schema:

Service (as you had it)

Subservice:

```
CREATE TABLE subservice (
   subservice_id serial not null primary key,
   name varchar(40),
   service_id integer not null references service(service_id)
)
```

Then you can select your subservices with:

```
SELECT name from subservice WHERE service_id = ?
```